# Best Loop For My VBA Task

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm really new in VBA coding, currently I have a spreadsheet contains groups and accounts at different levels, following are a simple example:

[image: Current Setup Image]

*Group* codes are all numbers and *Account* codes start with 3 letters, say ABC follow by 2 or 3 numbers, so an example would be ABC100, first 2 letter of account codes are always the same, i.e "AB" in the example, so another account code might be ABS80. *Group/Account* codes are in a separate column corresponding to the *groups/accounts*.

My aim is to set up a macro which would provide me with a summary, in a separate tab called say *results*, of all the *groups* (ONLY) above a given *Account/Group* in the hierarchy tree, with the subject *Account/Group* on the bottom.

So to illustrate using the above example. If the subject *Account* is `ABC100`, then after running the macro, I would expect to see in the *results* tab:

[image: Desired Result Image]

So far, I managed to get the macro to find the position of the subject *account* in the hierarchy and copy that row into the *results"* tab. But I'm stuck on the next step which is to extract only the direct upper level *groups* (at the same time ignore the *accounts* & *groups* in between) and paste them into the *results* tab.

I know that I need to use the loop and tried `For Next` with `If Then` statement in between, but keeps getting error messages. Really appreciate if someone could lead me to right direction on which loop to use.

Thanks! Below are my current codes:

```
Sub SearchRelevantAccGp()
'
' This macro finds the account or group and provides a summary of all affected groups
' within the Hierarchy

Dim searchvalue As Variant
searchvalue = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B2")
Dim hierarchy As Integer
    Sheets("Main Tree").Select
    cells.Find(What:=searchvalue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
hierarchy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)
Dim startref As Variant
startref = "I" & ActiveCell.Row
Dim rownumber As Integer
rownumber = ActiveCell.Row

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Result").Select
    Rows(hierarchy).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Main Tree").Select
Range(startref).Select
For i = rownumber To 2 Step -1
    If cells(i - 1, 9).Value - 1 = cells(i, 9).Value And cells(i - 1, 3).Value = "Group" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Result").Select
        Rows(hierarchy - 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This traverses the hierarchy backwards in "Results" which is a full copy of worksheet "Dashboard"

- Hides all rows, then unhides each relevant row, to avoid copying and pasting data

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowHierarchy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, found As Range, r As Long, nextR As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    Set found = ws.UsedRange.Columns(2).Find(What:="ABC10", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then                'ABC100 was found so we continue
        ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True    'hide all rows on Results sheet
        r = found.Row:  nextR = -1              'get found row, and move up to next row
        If r > 1 Then                           'make sure it wasn't found on row 1
            ws.Rows(1).Hidden = False           'unhide header row
            ws.Cells(1).Activate                'update display (scroll to top row)
            found.EntireRow.Hidden = False      'unhide found row
            Dim foundLvl As Long, nextLvl As Long, lvlRng As Range
            foundLvl = Val(found.Offset(0, 2))  'get current level from column D
            nextLvl = foundLvl                  'establish initial (minimum) level
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'turn off display
            While nextLvl > 1                   'loop while level is greater than 1
                Set lvlRng = found.Offset(nextR, 2)   'get next level from column D
                If Not IsError(lvlRng) Then     'check for errors (#N/A, #DIV/0!, etc)
                    nextLvl = Val(lvlRng)       'set next level
                    If nextLvl < foundLvl Then  'compare levels
                        If LCase(lvlRng.Offset(0, -3)) = "group" Then 'check Group in Col A
                            foundLvl = nextLvl  'set next minimum levele
                            lvlRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                nextR = nextR - 1               'move up to the next row, and repeat
            Wend
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True   'turn display back on
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

Comment: Thanks very much Paul for the solution. I guess the end result is the same in this case. I will try implementing the codes and see if that solves my problem.

Comment: Hi Paul, I've tested the code and unfortunately it did not work as expected. I think what went wrong is the way the code defines the "Group". You can see in my original data set that if it's an account code (ABC100) in column B, column A will show "Account" instead of "Group", which is the case in your screenshot. when I run the Macro, it only unhides the header row and the 'find' row. Also, the 'find' function is not based on matching the whole cell value, therefore if I'm to find "ABC10" for example, account "ABC109" would appear if it sits above "ABC10". Thanks! Jay

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned: it checks for the word "Group" in column A, and the `Find` function looks at the entire cell value - if you search for  "ABC10" it will not return value "ABC109"

Answer (score 0):

Consider no `For` loop or `If` logic and simply use SQL which you can in Excel for PC using the [Jet/ACE SQL Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) (Windows .dll files). Because your worksheet represents a table we can run various `WHERE` logic to output to *results* tab with [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel) method:

**SQL** *(embedded below, adjust SheetName and column headers as needed)*

```sql
SELECT [Type], [Account / Group ID], [Account / Group Name], [Hierarchy Position]
FROM SheetName$
WHERE (([Type] = 'Group' AND [Account / Group Name] NOT LIKE '%dupe%')
       OR ([Account / Group ID] = 'ABC100'))
  AND ([Hierarchy Position] <= (SELECT Max([Hierarchy Position]) 
                                FROM SheetName$ sub 
                                WHERE sub.[Account / Group ID] = 'ABC100'))
```

**VBA** *(connects to last saved instance of current workbook)*

```
Sub RunSQL()
    Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRINGS (TWO VERSIONS -ODBC/OLEDB)
    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
'    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
'                       & "Data Source=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
'                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection

    strSQL = "SELECT [Type], [Account / Group ID], [Account / Group Name], [Hierarchy Position]" _
              & " FROM SheetName$" _
              & " WHERE (([Type] = 'Group' AND [Account / Group Name] NOT LIKE '%dupe%')" _
              & "        OR ([Account / Group ID] = 'ABC100'))" _
              & "   AND ([Hierarchy Position] <= (SELECT Max([Hierarchy Position])" _
              & "                                 FROM SheetName$ sub" _
              & "                                 WHERE sub.[Account / Group ID] = 'ABC100'))"

    ' OPEN RECORDSET OF SQL RESULTS
    rs.Open strSQL, conn

    ' OUTPUT DATA TO EXISTING SHEET
     With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("results")
          ' COLUMN HEADERS
           For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
               .Cells(1, i) = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
           Next i    

          ' DATA ROWS
          .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

    rs.Close: conn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, this is much complicated then I anticipated and I think I will have to spend another 30 also hours research for SQL :) Really appreciate your help, one thing I noticed in your SQL though, one of the matching rules seems to be account name not having "dupe" in it. My example is really just to illustrate the data hierarchy and thus the account/group name are not reflecting the real data set. Account/group names in real data set can be anything and do not follow a particular pattern or contain certain words. So this being said, would the SQL still work? Cheers. Jay

Comment: I think this may work for your needs if *Type* will always be *Group* and *Account*. Except for the *dupe* and searching on *ABC100*, no where does query hard-code any names. Give it a try and see. If too complex, maybe future readers will find some use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  This used a variant array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2)

    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 2 To r
        If InStr(vDB(i, 3), "Group Level") Or vDB(i, 1) = "ABC100" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To 4
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    With toWs
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(1, 4) = Ws.Range("a1").Resize(1, 4).Value
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```